# Pdf is not getting open some time after BinaryWrite

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, itext

I created the functionality to edit the existing PDf content(adding some text and images) and after that i am opening this pdf file for print or download and i am using this code
Pdf is not getting open some time after `BinaryWrite`

```
byte[] outBuf = outStream1.GetBuffer();
HttpContext.Current.Response.Expires = 0;
HttpContext.Current.Response.Buffer = true;
HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent();
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition",  "attachment;filename="test.pdf");
HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentEncoding = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(outBuf);
outStream.Close();
HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
```

It is working fine on local machine or development server and some time on server.
On server after some times it is opening blank page. And after browser cache clear or temp file clear it works
I am not getting it where is the problem may be some client browser memory problem.
But if it is browser memory issue the it should also come on local too because I am using the same browser.

Please give me some idea or solution so that I can sort our this thing.

Comment: Definitely agree with @Guffa. Also, maybe I need more coffee but I can't seem to understand what `ContentEncoding` would be set to `UTF8`. For debugging purposes, if these changes don't work, try writing the bytes to disk on the server and then transferring/redirecting to that file.

Answer (score 1):

The [`GetBuffer` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.getbuffer.aspx) only returns exactly the content of the memory stream if it was created as a readonly stream from an array of bytes to begin with. Otherwise it returns the internal buffer, which may contain unused bytes at the end.

Use the [`ToArray` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.toarray.aspx) to get exactly the content of the memory stream, and nothing more:

```
byte[] outBuf = outStream1.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Another thing that triggers some browsers some of the time to treat your stream as PDF, is to append some dummy argument to your URL so that it ends with ".pdf". I am not sure if this is really necessary in your case since your are setting the 'content-disposition' to 'attachment'. It won't hurt though.